# react-native, truffle and expo

Tags: react-native, expo, truffle

I am developing a dapp and I want to create the frontend using react-native but I don't know how to do it. So please help me to setup this boilerplate.

**github repository is appreciated and thanks in advance**

Comment: What have you already done? Show us your code, so we could be able to help you.

Comment: here is my repository: https://github.com/praveenmanikandan/weird-commerce

Answer (score 0):

start by reading the react native official tutorial ( read "React Native CLI Quickstart " )

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

with a simple command you can create a blank project :

`react-native init AwesomeProject`

just follow official doc

Comment: I know how to create a react-native project but I don't know know how to connect react-native with truffle and web3